# Print module doesn't work with Panelizer module. Why?

Tags: panels

I need to make [**print pdf**](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module work on the panelizer node. But on page printpdf/node/nid, I see only the node title and panelizer field is not shown.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module uses `hook_preprocess_node` which is not used with panels_everywhere/panelizer. In a similar issue (with panels everywhere) I  used a patch `565856-panel_support_print-39.patch`.

Background discussion and the patch you can find here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/565856

Hope this will help.